# Get value from HTML element for display in Textbox

Tags: html, vb.net, web-scraping

I have tried adapting a handful of solutions Ive found on here and cannot get any to work. Most recently,

```
Private Sub Button4_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button4.Click
Dim Web As New HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlWeb
    Dim Doc As New HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument
    Doc = Web.Load("http://MyWebSearch.com/s/" + TextBox1.Text)
    For Each table As HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode In Doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes(<div class="inline-block"></div>)
        Textbox5.text(table.InnerText)
    Next
End Sub
```

I am trying to conduct a search with a fixed address where + textbox1 contains the search item. I need to return the value from one element on the page into Textbox5 after search is conducted. I cant for the life of me get this to work. Ive tried obtaining the xpath but that failed also. What am I doing wrong?

The web page is rbx.trade/s/"username"
I am trying to return the users "Rap" and display in textbox5

Answer (score 0):

You're searching for the class of an element.  You probably want to search for the ID instead.

```
For Each table As HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode In Doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes(<div id="elementID"></div>)
    Textbox5.text(table.InnerText)
Next
```

Or if you indeed mean to be using the class, store each value in an array or append to the text box instead of storing it directly.  Say there are 8 element with that class. Doing it the way you are will always store the value of the 8th skimmed element with that class name.

Comment: I am unable to locate any sort of ID of than the users.

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: On the web page, When I inspect element and look around I am unable to find any sort of id to use as a reference for the container. My apologies for improper terminology.

Comment: Well are even sure inline block is the class?  That is usually just a style applied to the element.

Comment: Updated with more info